# Base url for saved file in Android

Tags: android, css, base-url

My app saves a downloaded css file using this code:

```
outputStream = context.openFileOutput("content.css", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
outputStream.write(cssString.getBytes());
outputStream.close();
```

What base url do I use here:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("/baseURL/", this.html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

so that the this.html code can access the content.css file?

Comment: Try `"file://" + getFilesDir()`.

Comment: That didn't work. Nor did `"file://" + getFilesDir().getPath()`.

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked as the base URL parameter:

```
"file:///" + getFilesDir() + "/"
```

The web view content is now formatted with the downloaded css file.

Comment: That is difficult to believe as it would result in a path like `file:////data/data/<packagename>/files/` and i have never seen 4 slashes used.